# Perl Split Issue

Tags: perl

I'm using the split function to split a string on white space and for some reason split is keeping the white spaces in the array I'm saving it. Here's the code

```
while (<FP>) {
    if (/$END_SECTION/) { last; }
    if (/^\s*$/)        { next; }
    chomp;
    ( $name, $value ) = split m/:/, $_;
    print __LINE__, "name: $name Value: $value\n" if $debug;
    if ( $name =~ /Diameter/ ) {    #if Diameter is found
        print __LINE__, "Diameter: $value\n" if $debug;
        @fields = split /\s/, $value;
        print __LINE__, " Fields:@fields\n" if $debug;
        my $wafer_size = $fields[1];    #save index [0] to wafer_size
        print __LINE__, "Diameter: $wafer_size\n" if $debug;
        if ( $wafer_size =~ /8/ ) {
            $p->{Diameter} = "200";
        } elsif ( $wafer_size =~ /6/ ) {
            $p->{Diameter} = "150";
        }
        print __LINE__, "Diameter: $p->{Diameter}\n" if $debug;
    }
}
```

the text I'm splitting is this:

```
Wafer Diameter: 8 IN                                   
Flat Location (T,B,L,R): L   
Die X Step: 31800 UM  
Die Y Step: 25795 UM
```

when the code finds `/Diameter/` is saves the empty spaces in the `@fields` array. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `split` the line by `:` you get  `8 IN` in the `$value`. Note the leading space.

Then you are getting the expected behavior.  When a regex `/.../` is used the string is duly split by the given pattern and all substrings returned, except only for *trailing* spaces which are dropped.  There are a few details and special cases, please see [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

A notable example is a string with leading spaces, where with `/\s/` we get empty strings as first elements in the returned list. Even with `/\s+/` we get the empty string as the first element, since that precedes the whitespace matched by the pattern.

In your example there appears to be *one* leading space so one empty string is returned. I take it that by "*empty spaces in ... array*" you mean that there are array elements with "nothing."  Those are empty *strings*, there should be no spaces.

This can be changed by using the pattern `' '`, specifying any amount of any white space

> ... when the PATTERN is either omitted or a string composed of a single space character (such as `' '` or `"\x20"` , but not e.g. `/ /` ). In this case, any leading whitespace in EXPR is removed before splitting occurs, and the PATTERN is instead treated as if it were `/\s+/`; in particular, this means that any contiguous whitespace (not just a single space character) is used as a separator. However, this special treatment can be avoided by specifying the pattern `/ /` instead of the string `" "`, thereby allowing only a single space character to be a separator. In earlier Perls ...

So, if you don't care for multiple spaces use

```
my @fields = split ' ', $value;
```

Remember that with the near-equivalent `/\s+/` you have to watch for leading space.

---

Note that when using a *single* space (or tab) there can be surprises. For example, there can easily be a 'hidden' tab, when text and spaces happen to have the length of a tab so we don't notice any extra space as it all aligns right on the tab.

If there is no use of multiple spaces it is much safer to use `' '`.

Comment: I suspect that the problem has been wrongly-stated. Splitting `Wafer Diameter: 8 IN` on the colon will leave a `$value` starting with a single space. Splitting that on `\s` will produce a list with an empty string as the first element. Not the "blank space" that the OP describes.

Comment: @Borodin Oh, yes, that's what it is -- I misread it.  I thought that the problem is with splitting the part before the `:`, for some reason.  This is  clear now, I'll adjust. Thank you.